# Mixed-integer linear programming: How to generate constraints?

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I have an objective function such as

[image]

(for simplicity I omitted the coefficients).

I want to minimize this function using `intlinprog` with the following constraints:

[image]

and

[image]

with all x binary. These sums result in these 4 inequalities:

[image]

It is clear that the constaints matrix is

[image]

This works well if I create this matrix manually. Now suppose I have 6 or 8 or 10 variables instead of 4 in my objective function and in the constraints (same pattern). How can I use Matlab to generate this constraints matrix for these larger problems?

Comment: Not so easy for more complex models (for an example see [[link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/10/matlab-vs-gams-integer-programming.html)]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend writing down some other cases a bit. So it seems you want to constraint all row-sums and all column-sums:

For N=3, there are 9 vars (i'm assuming a square case here; you did not provide complete info):

```
x00 x01 x02
x10 x11 x12
x20 x21 x22
```

Now the constraint matrix looks like:

```
x00 x01 x02 | x10 x11 x12 | x20 x21 x22
---------------------------------------
1   1   1
              1   1   1
                            1   1   1
1             1             1
    1             1             1
        1             1             1
```

That's pretty regular. Not it's time to check out matlab's matrix-creation functions. Sadly i'm not much of a matlab-user, but:

**the lower half of rows consist of:**

- horizontal stacking of N identity-matrices each of size N

**the upper half of rows consist of**:

- block-diagonal matrix of N 1-row-vectors each of size N

**the final matrix is a vertical stacking of both components**

A full sparse-matrix python-example (sorry, no matlab here; but there should be nearly a 1:1 mapping), to be more clear would look like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

N = 3
component_a = sp.hstack([sp.eye(N) for i in range(N)])
row_full_1 = sp.csr_matrix(np.ones(N))
component_b = sp.block_diag([row_full_1 for i in range(N)])  # matlab: blkdiag?
matrix = sp.vstack((component_b, component_a))

print(matrix.todense())
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

**Remark:** depending on `N`, you need to think about using dense or sparse-matrices. Given `N`, the ratio of non-zeros in the matrix will be `1/N`.